# Python Selenium: How to access response objects in Network > XHR

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, response, httpresponse

I am working on a script that scrapes videos from a website using `Selenium`, these videos are passed as *.ts* chunks which are requested after reading the content of a *.m3u8* file containing all the links to these chunks as well as their order. For now, I can inspect the response objects manually and get the link of the *.m3u8* and pass it to my python script, but I want to fully automate the scraping process.

**Question:** How to access the response objects that I can find in `DevTools>Network>XHR>master.m3u8` directly from my python script?
[image: See screenshot]

Comment: There's probably a way to hook into it but pyppeteer / puppeteer has a nice page.on('response') method for this

Comment: @pguardiario could you provide me with the url?

Comment: The link to [pyppeteer](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer)